# Find the coefficients of this polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

#### Given $f(x)=x^4 +ax^3 +bx^2 -3x +5$ , $  a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and knowing that $i$ is a root of this polynomial. what are $a,b$?

My work until now: since all the coefficients are real, I now know that $i$ and $-i$ are roots of this polynomial, there must be two more roots. I tried to use vietta but it didn't really help, I get that $x_3+x_4=-a$ and $i(-i)x_3x_4=5$. What am I missing? 
Appreciate any help.

Comment: $i^4+ai^3+bi^2-3i+5=0$

Comment: Did you try to write what is $f(i)$ ?

Comment: Please, Vieta !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Alternative (but poor) solution:**

As we know that $\pm i$ are roots, $x^2+1$ is a factor. Then by long division we obtain the remainder

$$-(a+3)x+(-b+6).$$

But this remainder must vanish, and $a=-3,b=6$.

Comment: (+1) I added the long division.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=x^4 +ax^3 +bx^2 -3x +5$$

Since $i$ is a root, we have
$$f(i) = 0$$
$$\implies 1 -ia -b -3i + 5 = 0$$
$$\implies (6-b) + i (-a -3) = 0$$

Since $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, the real and imaginary part of the above expression must separately vanish.

Hence $$-a -3 = 0$$ and $$6 - b = 0$$

Finally
$$a = -3, b = 6$$

**Note**

In general, if $a = a_x + i a_y$ and $b = b_x + i b_y$, then we may have many solutions that satisfy $a_y - b_x + 6 = 0, a_x + b_y + 3 = 0$. Since $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, we must have $a_y = b_y = 0$

Comment: I don't think considering $-i$ brings something interesting to the issue.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yves Daoust and robjohn used the −i thing in their answers but didn't get a downvote. It's unfair toward PTSD

Comment: @Raffaele I didn't downvote it ! On the contrary, I upvoted the answer as soon as PTDS has erased his consideration of $-i$ which was **completely unnecessary for his kind of answer**.

Answer (score 1):

By long division,
$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
x^2+ax+(b-1)\\[-4pt]
x^2+1\enclose{longdiv}{x^4+ax^3+bx^2-3x+5}\\[-4pt]
\underline{x^4\phantom{\ +ax^3}+x^2\ }\phantom{-3x+5\ \ }\\[-2pt]
ax^3+(b-1)x^2-3x\phantom{\,+5\ \ }\\[-4pt]
\underline{ax^3\phantom{\,\,+(b-1)x^2}+ax}\phantom{\ +5}\\[-2pt]
(b-1)x^2-(a+3)x\ +5\\[-4pt]
\underline{(b-1)x^2\phantom{\ \qquad}+(b-1)}\\[-2pt]
-(a+3)x+(6-b)
\end{array}
$$
We must have that $-(a+3)x+(6-b)=0$. Therefore, $b=6\text{ and }a=-3$. Thus,
$$
\left(x^2+1\right)\left(x^2-3x+5\right)=x^4-3x^3+6x^2-3x+5
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(i)=i^4 + a i^3 + b i^2 - 3 i + 5=-i a-b+(6-3 i)=0$$
$$6-b-i(3+a)=0$$
as $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $6-b=0,3+s=0$

$a=-3,b=6$

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Raffaele. One observation: you probably need the fact that $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ Otherwise, you can have solutions like $a = -4 -5i, b = 1 + i$

Comment: In general, $a = a_x + i a_y, b = b_x + i b_y$ where $a_y - b_x + 6 = 0$ and $a_x+b_y+3 = 0$

Comment: If you set $a_y = b_y = 0$, you get the real solution.

Comment: @PTDS you are right! I inconsciously gave for granted that $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. I'll edit right now